# Flutter Firebase subscribe to multiple Firebase Cloud Messaging topics

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a relative beginner with Dart & right now for my Flutter app I am unsure on how to properly subscribe to multiple topics at once to Firebase Cloud Messaging. I want to receive notifications whenever my Cloud Function sends notifications through FCM to these topics at a certain time interval. The FlutterFire documentation seems to say that the **subscribe/unsubscribeToTopic** methods return Futures, but what is the best way in Dart to resolve multiple futures? So far, I have thought of 2 options below:

**Method 1**

```
Future<void> subscribeTopicV1(List<int> selectedUsers) async {
    for (var userId in selectedUsers) {
      await messaging.subscribeToTopic('$userId');
    }
}
```

My understanding is this basically turns all the subscribe/unsubscribe topic operations from asynchronous to synchronous if in the parent I call subscribeTopicV1 like the following:

```
...
if (shouldSubscribe) {
   await subscribeTopicV1
}
...
// OR
if (shouldSubscribe) {
   subscribeTopicV1.then( () => {
      ... // do whatever
   })
}
```

This should mean that I am waiting on each **messaging.subscribeToTopic** to return before I move on to subscribe the next topic?

**Method 2**

```
Future<void> subscribeTopicV2(List<int> selectedUsers) async {
     Future.wait(selectedUsers
         .map((userId) => messaging.subscribeToTopic('$userId')));
}
```

Now this second method would run all the **messaging.subscribeToTopic** operations in parallel and if I call subscribeTopicV2 in the same way like:

```
...
if (shouldSubscribe) {
   await subscribeTopicV2
}
...
// OR
if (shouldSubscribe) {
   subscribeTopicV2.then( () => {
      ... // do whatever
   })
}
```

In this second method, I should be waiting for when all futures are resolved inside subscribeTopicV2? I would like to mention that I do not care about the order in which the topics are subscribed so is it fair to say in this case I should be going with Method 2 for optimal performance since that it allows me to execute those async operations in parallel? I can't find any documentation of how people deal with subscribing to multiple topics so any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Both approaches sound fine to me, with the second one indeed likely to be faster. But honestly, whichever one works for you is probably fine.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!